# How DOM reference variable works

Tags: javascript, dom

All:

I am new to DOM, I got one question about DOM reference, for example(suppose I use D3.js or jQuery):

```
var domelement = d3.select("div#chart");
d3.select("div#chart").remove();
console.log(domelement);
```

When I print domelement, it still show an Object in the console even though it has been deleted from the DOM structure.

**So I am wondering, why this variable still has access to the DOM object?**

**How can I decide if a reference is invalid?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I am wondering, why this variable still has access to the DOM object?

You retrieved a reference to an object in memory and your variable will retain it for as long as you have it in scope.

You can mutate an object having a reference to it but you cannot destruct it (not in JS).

> How can I decide if a reference is invalid?

There is no such a thing as "invalid" reference. If you want to check if the element is still mounted in the DOM - you can just try to search for it. If it's there - you'll find it, and you will not otherwise.

Comment: So, dose that mean I can reload the element that I deleted before?

Comment: @Kuan what does "reload" mean?

Comment: means using something like append() to relink it to DOM structure.

Comment: @Kuan you can add it back indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`.remove()` returns the value (like a `return` function in javascript). When you use `console.log` this value is printed but it no longer exists in the DOM. HTML elements can exist as data nodes in javascript (`document.createElement`).

In this state, they exists as data, but haven't been added anywhere where they'd be visible. `.remove()` cuts the element out of the `body` and returns it in its data form, then `console.log` prints it.